# Can I get the linux-crashdump debain and its dependencies for ubuntu 14.04 image.

Tags: 14.04

crash dump test cases are failing in Juno because of difference in debian from 12.04 to 14.04. The required debian is not found from Internet. Can we get the linux-crashdump debain and its dependencies for 14.04 image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are asking for the location of the linux-crashdump deb files, and their dependencies (I don't have enough rep to comment on your question and ask for clarification).  These deb files for ubnuntu can be found at ftp://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, if you are looking to get them from the console.

If you are searching through these on your browser, a good resource is http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Here is a link to the linux-crashdump package for 14.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-crashdump

[image: A screenshot of packages.ubuntu.com]

You can see here that it depends on grub-pc and kdump-tools (which probably also have dependencies...), and you can download the deb files for both of these here as well.